# Trouble Saving Newly Created VBA Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm starting a new project and having trouble right at the start =[.  So often I need to pull out specific data from a very large excel sheet and create a new excel sheet for just that data.  At the moment I am currently trying to create a new workbook and save it to a file path.  I am getting the error on the `SaveAs` execution line.  Any idea why this might be happening?  The error is:

> "Method 'Save As' of object' _Workbook' failed.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim dat As String
Dim Client As String

Path = "C:\Back\Test\"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control Panel").Activate
dat = Range("F42")
Client = Range("F43")

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Date & "-" & Client & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
newWBName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: Can you show the Filename with a MsgBox? Like: MsgBox (Path & Date & "-" & Client & ".xls")

Comment: You don't happen to have mixed dat (from dat = Range("F42")) and Date (from Filename:=Path & Date & ...)?

Comment: Elzell yes I can (the message box).  That was a typo on my part, but it's still not executing.

Comment: Works fine for me ... do you have proper writing permissions in the folder where you want to save? What does the MsgBox show exactly?

Comment: Worked for me as well. Make sure you have proper permission for the folder `"C:\Back\Test\"`.

Comment: Will date evaluate to 3 folders dd mm yyyy in a path?  Try format(date,"ddmmyyyy")

Comment: The MsgBox shows C:\Back\Test\11/24/2015-ClientTest.xls

Comment: Nathan the problem is the date.  I just changed it and it executed properly.  Much appreciated!.  Thank you I appreciate it.  And thanks elzell for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will propose my access to your need.

Here is sub which should do what you need. So first i recomend to Dim all of your variables and do not use activate. Instead use sheet variable and also acces single values via cells not via range.

But your main issue maybe is that you try to use reserved word `Date`. Let me know if something isnt clear to you.

```
Sub save()

Dim filePath As String
Dim dateFromSheet As String
Dim clientName As String
Dim controlPanelSheet As Worksheet
Dim newWorkbookName As String

Set controlPanelSheet = Sheets("Control Panel")

filePath = "c:\Users\sukl\Documents\"

With controlPanelSheet
    dateFromSheet = .Cells(42, "F").Value
    clientName = .Cells(43, "F").Value

End With

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filePath & dateFromSheet & "-" & clientName & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
newWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```